# How to decrypt storage for s4

Tags: password, encryption

How to decrypt storage for Samsung S4, there a password that I never do before, so how can I find the password, because I never make a password for decrypt storage before.

Answer (score 0):

After you've enabled encrypted storage, the password is the same as your lock screen password.